# Basic Syntax vs SQL Command -- Formula Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sqlcommand

I am trying to convert this statement into a SQL command-- for testing and learning purposes.

The code in a formula in basic syntax is

```
if IsNumeric (Mid(Trim(X), 1)) Then
formula = UCASE(TRIM(MID(X, (INSTR (X, " ", 1) +1)))))
ELSE
formula = X.
```

What am I supposed to use instead of formula in the sql command and should this be done in sql command for efficiency? Even if I am not supposed to, I would like to know how to write this in sql command.

So far I have

```
CASE ISNUMERIC (Mid(Trim(X), 1)) Then
[BLANK] = UCASE(TRIM(MID(X, (CHARINDEX (X, " ", 1) +1)))))
ELSE
[BLANK] = X
```

EPV

**Sample of Data.  So when I import/link data from the back end. My X Field looks like a variety of:**
 1. 'zzabc123 - The Red Car'
 2. 'abc123 - The Black Car'
 3. 'The green car'

I want to create a SQL code where:

- CHECK X (zzabc123 - the red car) to see if there is a zzabc123 in the front
- if it is numeric, then cut out the front part - by using charindex to find where the space starts and grab only 'the red car'.
- If it is not numeric, just clean up the DATA part
- END CASE
- After that case evaluate the DATA and use another CASE to find key words to use a generalized term for reporting.
- **RESULTS**
- RED CAR
- BLACK CAR
- GREEN CAR

  ```
  SELECT *,
  CASE ISNUMERIC(Mid(Trim(X), 1)) Then
  UCASE(TRIM(MID(X, (CHARINDEX (X, " ", 1) +1)))))
  ELSE X
  END

  CASE WHEN X LIKE '%RED%'
  THEN 'RED CAR'
  ELSE X LIKE '%BLACK%;
  THEN 'BLACK CAR'
  ELSE X LIKE '%GREEN%'
  THEN 'GREEN CAR'
  ELSE XY
  END

  FROM XTABLE`
  ```

Comment: Can you please post a few sample records, and explain the conditions for your CASE statement?  It looks to me like you're trying to check if a field is numeric, and if so you want to select everything up to the position of a space

Comment: Thank you, I edited my posting with an exact example of what I am trying to accomplish. @AHiggins

Comment: Looks good!  Out of curiosity, will there always be that 'space dash space' between?

Comment: @AHiggins, as of right now it appears as though the imported messy ones do. I am kind of conused of the +1 in the Mid code, and also confused on how the code (previously) knows to only grab the DATA after the space dash space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of your data and what you are trying to accomplish, it's next to impossible to accurately give you a SQL sample.

That said, here is a conversion of most of your functions to their SQL-Server equivalents; if you can look up items like the `SUBSTRING()` and `CHARINDEX()` functions, and adapt the sample to do whatever it is your requirements dictate, this should get you started.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(X)), 1,1)) = 0
        THEN UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(X, CHARINDEX(X, ' ')+1, LEN(X) - CHARINDEX(X, ' ')))))
        ELSE 'X'
    END
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: I created a sample and if it's still the same to this one, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN ISNUMERIC (Mid(Trim(X), 1)) THEN
    UCASE(TRIM(MID(X, (CHARINDEX (X, " ", 1) +1)))))
  ELSE
    X
END
```